# Keeping the same Task attributes for incoming SMS sent to Flex

Tags: twilio

The task attributes listed here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-queue-calls#task-attributes-linking-tasks-to-calls appear to be added to both incoming calls and SMS and are accessible in Studio via helper functions such as {{trigger.message.FromCity}}, {{trigger.message.FromState}} etc. However, when selecting incoming messages to be routed to Flex Proxy Service, only a small handful of the attributes become accessible in both Studio and Flex.

How can I route incoming SMS to Flex and still be able to have the same Task attributes added to each task?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually type in the additional trigger widget metadata attributes in to the Studio Send to Flex Widget using the liquid syntax examples you provided. They would go under the "Attributes" edit box of that Widget.

You just add them to the below required attributes when sending into Flex.

> {"name": "{{trigger.message.ChannelAttributes.from}}", "channelType":
>   "{{trigger.message.ChannelAttributes.channel_type}}", "channelSid":
>   "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}"}

Comment: Please click the link I provided above. {{trigger.message.FromCity}}, {{trigger.message.FromState}}, {{trigger.message.FromZip}} and so forth do not return values on incoming SMS tasks when tasks are routed to Flex.

Comment: The majority of attributes listed here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/trigger-start for Inbound Message Triggers do not appear as part of task attributes when incoming SMS is sent to Flex, even when the SendToFlex widget lists them all.

Comment: And you are manually adding these attributes to the Send to Flex Widget attributes edit box?

Comment: Yes. Adding {{trigger.message.FromCity}}, {{trigger.message.FromState}}, {{trigger.message.FromZip}} to the Send to Flex Widget for Incoming SMS does not return any value in the Task attributes.